# How do I lock scrolling to left and right in the Apps view in Windows 8.1 Start Menu?

Tags: windows-8, start-menu

At some point in the past I had my start screen set up so that when I hit the Windows Key and go to the Apps view, I could scroll freely with my mouse wheel and it would only bring me left and right through my installed programs.  The default behavior is that scrolling up will bring you to the Live Tiles and scrolling down will do nothing.  I cannot find this setting again to save my life and I really hate the Lives Tiles..  Does anybody know where this setting lives?!

Comment: did you have this enable when you were using 8.0 by chance?

Comment: It's possible I suppose before I upgraded to 8.1.  Was that a feature that was removed?

Comment: Some of the behavior on the start screen was changed.  For instance I don't believe `Apps View` even existed in 8.0 and if it did it wasn't default view.  Can you post the Start Menu Properties window for us?

Comment: Well I feel silly now..  I don't know if it was a reboot or what but now the behavior is back to how I wanted it.